# Function concerning change of fractions

Tags: functions, numerics

I was working on a way of calculating the square root of a number by the method of x/y → (x+4y)/(x+y) as shown by bobbym at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861509/

I tried to do it via functions on mathematica, everything seems correct. Why am I not seeing 2.5 as the answer? How can I fix it?
[image: code]

Comment: I think you are missing an underbar in your definition of f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

a = 1;

b = 4;
```

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) will provide the general result for arbitrary `n`

```
Clear[f]; f[n_] = RSolveValue[{
    f[n + 1] == (Numerator[f[n]] + b*Denominator[f[n]])/
      (Numerator[f[n]] + Denominator[f[n]]), f[1] == a}, f[n], n] //
  FullSimplify

(* -2 - 4/(-1 + (-(1/3))^n) *)
```

`f` is complex for non-integer `n`

```
f[1.5]

(* 1.85714 - 0.742307 I *)
```

It is real for integer `n`

```
f /@ Range[10] // Simplify

(* {1, 5/2, 13/7, 41/20, 121/61, 365/182, 1093/547, 3281/1640, 
    9841/4921, 29525/14762}

Show[
 Plot[Re[f[n]], {n, 1, 10}, PlotRange -> All],
 DiscretePlot[f[n], {n, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Red, Filling -> None]]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Alternatively, use [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html) and [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html)

```
Clear[f2]; seq = RecurrenceTable[{
   f2[n + 1] == (Numerator[f2[n]] + b*Denominator[f2[n]])/
     (Numerator[f2[n]] + Denominator[f2[n]]), f2[1] == a}, f2[n], {n, 8}]

(* {1, 5/2, 13/7, 41/20, 121/61, 365/182, 1093/547, 3281/1640} *)

f2[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // FullSimplify

(* 2 + 4/(-1 + (-3)^n) *)
```

`f` and `f2` are equal for integer values of `n`

```
f[n] == f2[n] // Simplify[#, n ∈ Integers] &

(* True *)
```

Their real parts are equal

```
Re[f[n]] == Re[f2[n]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(* True *)
```

They are complex conjugates of each other

```
f[n] == Conjugate[f2[n]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify

(* True *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Consider using `NestList` to see how the solution evolves with every step. The square root of `num` is being calculated starting at various initial values as shown on [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/861509/what-is-the-sum-that-the-square-root-button-on-calculator-does-so-i-can-do-it-wi) page.

```
nsteps = 10;
num = 6;
evols = NestList[(Numerator@# + num Denominator@#)/(
     Numerator@# + Denominator@#) &, #, nsteps] & /@ Range[1, 3, 0.5]

ListLinePlot[evols
 , PlotRange -> All
 , InterpolationOrder -> 2
 ]
```

[image]

---

*EDIT*

To get the numbers from the first answer on the linked page, start at `1/2` and use `2` as the number whose square root is needed.

```
NestList[(Numerator@# + 2 Denominator@#)/(
  Numerator@# + Denominator@#) &, 1/2, 5]
```

$$\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{5}{3},\frac{11}{8},\frac{27}{19},\frac{65}{46},\frac{157}{111}\right\}$$

Comment: I changed the numbers on purpose. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 5):

Another option is is to use basic Do loop or a Table.

```
update[a_Integer, b_Integer] := (a + 2*b)/(a + b)
a = 1;
b = 2;
lis = Last@
  Reap@Do[ t = update[a, b];  a = Numerator[t]; b = Denominator[t]; 
    Sow[a/b],
    {n, 1, 10}
    ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
N[lis]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Sqrt[2]//N
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are at least 8 more ways to do this in Mathematica.

Answer (score 4):

Following Syed's idea, but using `FoldList`:

```
FoldList[(Numerator@# + 2 Denominator@#)/(Numerator@# + Denominator@#) &, 1/2, Range[5]]

(*{1/2, 5/3, 11/8, 27/19, 65/46, 157/111}*)
```

Answer (score 3):

This can also be approached recursively:

```
Clear[f]; a = 1; b = 4; f[1] = a;
f[n_] := f[n] = (Numerator[f[n - 1]] + b Denominator[f[n - 1]])
               /(Numerator[f[n - 1]] + Denominator[f[n - 1]])
```

Then the fist 10 values can be calculated

```
f /@ Range[10]
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the [linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/861534) answer at *Mathematica Stack Exchange*, this method of calculating square roots is described in **Square Roots From Anywhere** by Terry A. Goodman and John Bernard, *Mathematics Teacher*, Vol 73, May 1979, p344-345. The JSTOR link is [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27961659).

To calculate $\sqrt n $, "starting with two counting numbers *a* and *b*":

$$
     \frac{a}{b}\to \frac{a + n b}{a+b}
$$

This may be implemented recursively with [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html) (and [#0](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html#24637)) as follows, where *i* is the number of iterations:

```
fun1[n_,a_,b_,i_]:=(j=i;If[j>0, --j;
        #0[Sow[(Numerator[#] + n Denominator[#])/(Numerator[#] + Denominator[#])]]
      ]&[a/b]//Reap)[[2,1]]


  func[81,1, 2,27]//Short
```

[image]

Alternatively, with [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html):

```
fun2[n_,a_,b_,tolerance_]:=FixedPointList[
 (Numerator@# + n Denominator@#)/(Numerator@# +Denominator@#)&, 
  a/b, SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < tolerance &)]

 fun2[81,1,2, 0.1]//Short
```

[image]

To append a decimal representation of the final estimate:

```
fun1d[n_,a_,b_,i_]:=(j=i;If[j>0, --j;
    #0[Sow[(Numerator[#] + n Denominator[#])/(Numerator[#] + Denominator[#])]],Sow[N[#]]
  ]&[a/b]//Reap)[[2,1]]
```

Applying the above to the OP example (find $\sqrt 4$ with *a* = 1, *b* = 1):

```
fun1d[4,1,1,5]
```

$$
\left\{\frac{5}{2},\frac{13}{7},\frac{41}{20},\frac{121}{61},\frac{365}{182},2.00549\right\}
$$

As pointed out in the [linked](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27961659) paper:

$$\frac{a+b n}{a+b} = \frac{\frac{a}{b}+n}{\frac{a}{b}+1}$$

and the method may also be (recursively) implemented as follows:

```
fun3[n_,a_,b_,i_]:=(j=i;If[j>0, --j;#0[Sow[(# + n)/(# + 1)]]]&[a/b]//Reap)[[2,1]]

fun3[81,1,2,5]
```

[image]

Or, using [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html):

```
fun4[n_,a_,b_,tolerance_]:=FixedPointList[(# + n)/(# +1)&, a/b,
   SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < tolerance &)]

fun4[81,1,2,0.001]//Short
```

[image]